# How do you restrict an azure resource from being deployed within a resource group with a tag applied to a resource group?

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I've configured the policy as follows. It is not functioning and I am asking for some help. How do you configure this azure policy rule to deny a storage account from being created in a resource group based on the tag value?

```
"policyRule": {
  "if": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups"
          },
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.storage/storageaccounts"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "field": "tags.RestrictStorage",
        "equals": "true"
      }
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "deny"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- `allof` is an equivalent of the logical operator `AND` while  `anyOf`
  is an equivalent of `OR` operator .

Since you want to restrict the creating of storage account under certain resource group based on the tags  added it will look something like this :

```
 "policyRule":
 {
    "if":
{    
    "allOf":
            [
                {
                    "allOf":
                                [
                                    {
                                        "field":"type",
                                        "equals":"Microsoft.storage/storageaccounts"
                                    },
                                   {    
                                        "field":"type",
                                        "type":"Microsoft.resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups"
                                    }
                                ]
                },
                {
                   "field": "tags.RestrictStorage",
                    "equals": "true"
                }
            ]

},
"then":
        {
            "effect": "deny"
        }
}
```

**Refer:**

[Details of the policy definition structure - Azure Policy | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Policy)

[Tutorial: Create a custom policy definition - Azure Policy | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/tutorials/create-custom-policy-definition?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Policy)

Comment: this doesn't work because you can't have two conflicting field types in a single allOf.